# Clicking "Download MP3" downloads 0kb file

Tags: audio

I have a problem on my client's Wordpress site. The client has MP3 files that they would like to be able to be played in the browser but also be downloadable. Playing in the browser isn't a problem, but when the "Download MP3" link is clicked it opens the "Save/Save As" browser dialogue and then downloads a 0kb file with the correct file name.

I'm new to Wordpress development... any ideas on how to get the downloads to work properly? Here's a link to a representative example: https://calvarypo.org/multimedia-archive/who-can-make-war-against-him-revelation-133-18/?player=audio

I've tried disabling each plugin used on the site one-by-one but that did not get the downloads working. The one plugin I did not disable was the "Embed Any Document" plugin because there are a lot of documents embedded on the site and I didn't want to mess them up.

I've found other questions about downloads on Wordpress sites, but none of them seemed to answer my question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: WP doesn't have this functionality out of the box, how is this link implemented? Is this a feature of the Risen theme? 3rd party theme support is off topic here and not in this stacks scope, this isn't a place to report bugs for https://churchthemes.com/themes/risen/. Contact their support or ask other users of this theme

Comment: Tom's right that this is out of scope, but you've got some bad links being generated by whatever part of your theme/plugin is creating the links: `https://calvarypo.org/?download=https%3A%2F%2Fcalvarypo.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2021%2F01%2FS-1422-KL.mp3`

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I wasn't aware this was functionality provided by the theme (that's how new I am to Wordpress). I will contact the theme creators for support.